# Detect iPhone iOS Dark Mode w/ React Native

Tags: react-native

I know this is possible using Swift:

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
        print("Light mode")
    } else {
        print("Dark mode")
    }
}
```

However, is there a way of doing this with JavaScript ?

Comment: Looking inside github.com/facebook/react-native issues I only found this one : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25322 which was auto-closed by the bot.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You don't need `react-native-dark-mode` since 0.62.2.
You can use

```
import { Appearance } from 'react-native'
...
Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark'
```

Here's a commit that adds it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/63fa3f21c5ab308def450bffb22054241a8842ef

Answer (score 2):

Yes...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dark-mode

OR

https://github.com/codemotionapps/react-native-dark-mode

```
import { useDarkMode } from 'react-native-dark-mode'

function Component() {
  const isDarkMode = useDarkMode()
  return <View style={{ backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'black' : 'white' }} />
}
```

Comment: The auto linking did not work for me on RN0.6+ when the latest module is installed. I had to run:
 `react-native link react-native-dark-mode` 
`cd ios`
`pod install`
Before it registered